# How 3d games stores textures in a idevice (Assuming large texture requirement)?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I always wondered, how a typical 3d game implements texture uploading. (Consider a 3d game TempleRun, It seems like, without a single texture reloading entire 'run' gets completed)

I am developing a simple 2d game for iphone, already I am getting "Memory warning level 1..2" in main scene itself. I solved this before, but I was wondering if their is a new way.

Are they doing some special dynamic texture uploading, new texture format or using good old techniques such as PVRTC texture, texture atlas etc?

I just want know if their any new technique to handle large textures in iPhone (special extension)?

Comment: This may sound trivial but are you using texture atlases rather then loading in textures individually? Also are you using cocos2d?

Comment: are you storing textures with size that is power of two?

Comment: @shoughton123 Yes, I am using cocos2d. I use CCSpriteBatchNode for some of the textures. Not for all.

Comment: Ah okay, was just checking that you were.

Comment: @medvedNic No. I believe cocos2d 2.0 handles it. (CC_TEXTURE_NPOT_SUPPORT).  Correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: then it is ok.. maybe you should try clearing the texture cache when transitioning between scenes? and how have you "solved this before"?

Comment: @medvedNick As I mention earlier, making texture atlas. Tools like TexturePacker was really helpful. But, when I see a 3d game, its overwhelming. It makes me feel like, textures are getting uploaded in a secondary thread.

Answer (score 0):

I know in Unity 3D engine the textures and materials are stored as image files and either loaded dynamically as resources during runtime, and the engine itself is responsible for allocating and deallocating the resource from and out of memory.

The 3D engine takes care of all the memory management and makes good use of it.

Comment: I want to know little bit more about dynamical texture loading.. Specific links?